# Why doesn't Twitter bootstrap class navbar-fixed-top work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"> <!-- header nav -->
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <ul class="nav">

            <li class="active">
              <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="#">About us</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="#">Derp</a>
            </li>

          </ul>

          <span class="brand"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="span3" style="background:grey; height:200px;"></div>
        <div class="span9" style="background:lightgrey; height:20000px;"></div>

      </div>

    </div> 

    <div class="footer" style="height:100px"> <!-- footer --> 
    </div> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" scr="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And for some reason, the navigation bar styles perfectly, however it doesn't seem to fix itself to the top of the page when scrolling. It seems so trivial... what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work fine here.

However, bootstrap-responsive, in smaller layout, unfix the nav bar in order to optimize the space...

You can try to remove `bootstrap-responsive.css` and see if it works.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D9S3z/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I took your exact HTML and everything looks good to me:
[view live](http://www.bootply.com/render/64248)
[edit](http://www.bootply.com/64248)

A couple of things you could check.

Remember that by default, the fixed-top behaviour is removed for tablets and below, so make sure you are checking at viewport > 767px. Also you have an older version of jQuery (v1.10.1) so probably good to use something more recent.

Hope this helps!